# MySQL update via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I try to update an SQL table but my code won't work. Maybe someone can take a look please.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE( `description` ,  "Instagram:",  "" ";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I get a 500 error.

When I execute this directly in the database it works very well:

```
UPDATE pm_videos 
SET `description` = REPLACE(`description`, "Instagram:",  "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,                $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET       `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,  'Instagram:',  '')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " .            $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

You had a few syntax errors in your code try the above

Comment: When I want replace one word it works well but when I want to delete sets like this 
Watch the full episodes of Tonight With Boy Abunda on TFC.TV ...   it doenst work. The file runs well but it doesn't delete this set. Do you hav an idea. Thank you

Comment: Try running the query with out the dot in it and let me know if it works

Comment: Ignore that last comment will look into it now

Comment: Comment with the exact query your trying to rub

Comment: The code looks like this

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET       `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,  'Watch the full episodes of Tonight With Boy Abunda on TFC.TV',  '')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " .            $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

but it doesn't replace it

Comment: After the comma at the end of the query it's needs to be ' ' not speech marks

Comment: I forgot to copy the ' ' in the last post
Its seems to be when I add words like this You're or TFC.TV

Comment: No it seems to be working because I put now all insie with <br>

Comment: Sorry Adam one last question. What i need to add, when I want to replace like this 
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET       `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,  'Instagram:',  '')";
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET       `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,  'Facebook:',  '')";

Can I write this directly under the first line?

Comment: No as this will just update the database straight away to Facebook, you need to give me more details of what you are trying to achive

Comment: Please have a look here: http://showtime.com.ph/watch.php?vid=970b7ceab# In the description I try to remove 
Subscribe to ABS-CBN Entertainment channel! - 
Watch the full episodes of It’s Showtime on TFC.TV 
and on IWANT.TV for Philippine viewers, click: 
Visit our official website! 
Facebook:

Comment: So it looks like in the table: Jhong Hilario competes with Axel Torres in GagamBattle.<br />Subscribe to ABS-CBN Entertainment channel! - <br />Watch the full episodes of It’s Showtime on TFC.TV  <br />and on IWANT.TV for Philippine viewers, click: <br />Visit our official website! <br />Facebook: <br />Twitter: <br />Instagram:

Comment: so is this just for this one video?

Comment: No for each video but the description is almost the same

Comment: The videos are autoimport and at the end i'll run a cronjob after I figured out how I can remove these lines via PHP :).

Comment: try adding that line after the first and let me know if it works

Comment: Only the second line has been removed (Facebook) the first one (Visit our official website! ) is still there.

Comment: What is it you actually want removing? is it now just the Visit our official website or is it more ?

Comment: only the first set should be there

Answer (score 1):

you are messed up with quotes problem.try this changes

```
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET  `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,  'Instagram:',  '' )";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because PHP assumes you are closing a statement when you include a `"` inside another `"`. To fix this, just include single quotation inside double quotes, like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET description = REPLACE(`description` ,  'Instagram:', '');";
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've improperly concatenated the strings "Instagram": and "".

Try this code:

```
 $sql = 'UPDATE pm_videos SET  `description` = REPLACE(  `description` ,  "Instagram:",  ""); ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use single quote or double quote like this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE pm_videos SET `description` = REPLACE( `description` ,  'Instagram:',  '' ";
```